# NuxtJS site misdirects URLs with params (and no www) to wrong domain

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404, middleware

I have a NuxtJS site which correctly resolves URLs with and without www subdomain. However, I have noticed that when I navigate to a nested page without the `www` subdomain, such as `https://heidivogler.de/angebot/reittherapie`, the URL is incorrectly redirected to https://www.heidivogler.de/angebote/reittherapie which returns a 404 error.

```
        ▽▽▽--- the subdomain is added, that's ok
https://www.heidivogler.de/angebote/reittherapie
but weirdly also this e ----------△
```

To clarify: 
`https://www.heidivogler.de/angebot/reittherapie` → `https://www.heidivogler.de/angebot/reittherapie` ✓
`https://heidivogler.de/angebot/reittherapie` → `https://www.heidivogler.de/angebote/reittherapie` ✗

My pages directory structure is as follows:

```
pages/
- angebot/
-- [slug].vue
- [slug].vue
- angebote.vue
- index.vue
- kontakt.vue
- termine.vue
- ueber-mich.vue
```

```js
import i18n from './config/i18n'
import postcss from './config/postcss'
import sitemap from './config/sitemap'
import image from './config/image'
import meta from './config/meta'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' },
    head: meta.head
  },
  modules: [
    'nuxt-simple-sitemap',
    '@nuxtjs/strapi',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxt/image-edge',
    '@formkit/nuxt'
  ],
  nitro: {
    compressPublicAssets: true,
  },
  formkit: {
    configFile: '~/config/formkit.config.ts',
  },
  strapi: {
    url: process.env.API_BASE || 'http://localhost:1337',
  },
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '~/assets/css/transitions.css',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
  ],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      mapbox: {
        token: process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN,
      },
      email: {
        to: process.env.ADDRESS_TO
      },
      siteUrl: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL,
      siteName: meta.head.title,
      siteDescription: meta.head.meta.find((m) => m.name === 'description')?.content,
      language: 'de-DE',
    }
  },
  i18n,
  postcss,
  image,
  extends: [
    'nuxt-seo-kit'
  ],
})
```

Any ideas?